# Unable to log into TFS2015 from web or VS2015

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015, tfs-2015

- Server O/S: windows Server 2008 R2 x64
- TFS: TFS 2015.1
- VS: VS2015.2

Brand new install of Server and TFS. Unable to connect to the web admin portal for TFS using http://{server}:18080/tfs. What happens is that it pops up a username and password box and does not allow for authentication from outside the server or on the server itself. According to the Application Tier the notification and web access url are both the server name and not my FQDN for access outside the router. And the server URL is localhost.

Where can I add user accounts so they can hit the Web Access as well as from VS?

**Update 1**

I can now login using http://localhost:18080/tfs from the server itself. However when I try to log in using http://{machine name}:18080/tfs , I get a user login prompt that will not log me in.

Comment: Have you tried logging in with the Admin-Windows Account you installed the instance with ?

Comment: yes. I tried that as well as creating a new account.

Answer (score 1):

Well,... I finally found out why it was not authenticating... and I kicked my self for not checking this earlier.

Seems that when I did an install of 2008 R2, the user account did not have a password set for it and I over looked it (what happens at 0300 in the morning). Set the password and now EVERYTHING works the way it is supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

TFS uses Windows Integrated Authentication, so, if your server is joined to an Active Directory domain, you must use account from that (or a trusted) domain. If your server is not joined, known as Workgroup mode, then you have to create user locally.

TFS is pretty agnostic on the URL, so that is usually not an issue (you can even use IP address).

Comment: Tried a admin user - no luck. I have 3 different bindings I can possibly, localhost, the machine name and the fqdn.